# Using BindingSource to bind to Nested Properties - or, Making Entities Bindable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

Binding to a nested property is easy enough:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bindingSource, "myProperty")); //Normal binding
checkBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", bindingSource, "myProperty.innerProperty")); //Nested property
```

However, when `myProperty.innerProperty` is changed, no events are raised - **the BindingSource is never notified of the change.**

I've [read](http://www.msnewsgroups.net/csharp/t19891-nested-objects-inotifypropertychanged.aspx) that the solution is to *"make sure that when the `innerProperty` object raises the `PropertyChanged` event, the `MyProperty` class that contains `innerProperty` captures the event and also raises a `PropertyChanged` event of its own."*

However, entity framework [does not do this for me](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532257), and I'd rather not go through every instance of every class and wire-up a custom method to every navigation property, just to make the my classes bindable.  **Is there a decent workaround to make entities bindable?**

Comment: Here are some magic beans that... Ah, hell, I feel for ya; lemme ditch the sarcasm.  There isn't a magic bullet (or bean) for this problem.  Best solution for you is to use the EF4 T4 templates and rewrite them so that myProperty listens for changes to innerProperty.

Comment: The only way to do this is to introduce a number of wrapper types which will encapsulate the EF types and propagate change notifications the way you want.

Comment: You probably don't want to hear it, but don't bind to your entities. Use MVVM with something like automapper to reduce the mapping tedium. I've been down the entity-binding path before and you end with with so much UI-supporting guff in your entity classes that even manually mapping ViewModels starts to look appealing.

Comment: Did you try the workaround mentioned in the MS Connect issue you cited?  (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532257)

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement INotifyPropertyCHanged on your class.

Your property should look something like this.

```
private bool _checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return _checked; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _checked)
            {
                _checked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyCHanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this works for winforms. It works for WPF and Silverlight.

Comment: It nicest when you use some MvvM pattern for doing this

Comment: *"Checked"* is the name of the property we're binding *to*, not binding *from*.  However, more importantly, I already mentioned this answer in the question - but this is not an option in EF.

Answer (score 0):

You could try POCO Entity Generator or the EF Code-First feature, which is still in [CTP](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx).

Both approaches require EF4 though.

Answer (score 0):

Are your properties changed via the same context used by the UI?

If so, edit the T4 file you use to create your entities.
- Make it create INotifyPropertyChanged entities, with properties that notify on changes and have an explicit field behind.